# Putting all template files in app/Resources/views/ and their assets in Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, twig

[Symfony best practises](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html) tells that storing all template files in `app/Resources/views/` is a good practice.

I tried to do that, but I have problem with assets. The command assets:install don't get assets from `app/Resources/public`, `app/Resources/views/public`.

I don't see the idea of putting all templates in `app/Resouces/views` when I can't put in the same place assets.

Any solution? I have tried some solutions from other stackoverflow questions, but it didn't work on Symfony 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That best practice just talks about views - not static assets.

There is a separate best practice for [Web Assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)